# Using @{} in multicolumn in spreadtab

Tags: tables, formatting, spreadtab

I want to be able to run this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}}
        @Test & 1234\\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{@Longer}
    \end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

I can run this without errors:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}}
        @Test & 1234\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{@Longer}
    \end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

But that produces the wrong alignment:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a new columntype which hides the problematic @:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype\mCol{@{}l@{}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}}
        @Test & 1234\\        
        \multicolumn{2}{\mCol}{@Longer}
    \end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```